# React Navigation calling parent navigation stack in child

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

The Goal
Using react navigation, navigate from a child screen to a parent screen

More Detail
If I have the following Navigator structure:

Parent Navigator :
screen 1 (stack screen)
screen 2 (stack screen)
screen 3 (stack screen)
screen 4 (stack screen) -> : child screen :
screen A (drawer screen)
screen B (drawer screen)

question :-
can i render screen 4 child screen A from parent navigator and again redirect to the parent navigator screen 2

try : i am making a login screen , register screen and optp screen (one time pasword)

parent nvaigation container :
login (button clicked) -> register (button clicked) -> optp (button clicked) -> child drawer component

child drawer component :- (drawer screen one , drawer screen 2 , drawer screen 3 (logout))

WANT:
drawer screen logout , drawer screen clicked goes to parent navigation screen Login

Comment: You can use navigation.navigate("ScreenName") to navigate to any desired screen of your choice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.